# Flat algebras and tensor product

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

All rings are commutative. Suppose $B$ is a flat $A$-algebra, and that $M$ and $N$ are flat $B$-modules.

Is there a way to compare the two $A$-modules $M \otimes_A N$ and $M \otimes_B N$?

Thanks

Comment: Well, the natural map $M \times N \rightarrow M \otimes_B N$ is $B$-bilinear, hence also $A$-bilinear, so there is an induced $A$-module map $M \otimes_A N \rightarrow M \otimes_B N$.  Moreover the map is surjective.  Are you looking for more than that as an answer?

Comment: I am wondering if there are any reasonable conditions on the map $A\to B$ which will make this map an isomorphism.

Comment: Suitable conditions on $M$ and $N$ will also be good.

Comment: Hmm.  Notice that if $B/A$ is a proper field extension and $M,N$ are nonzero finite-dimensional vector spaces, then the map will not be an isomorphism.  In some sense, these modules and rings are as nice as possible.  So I think you need to be a bit more specific as to what you're looking for.

Comment: ***Moderator Note*** Let's keep comments civil, constructive and on-topic, or I'll need to have some private chats with folks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $B$ is a localization of $A$ then the natural map $M\otimes_A N \to M\otimes_B N$ will be an isomorphism (without any assumption on $M$ and $N$).

How definitive is this example?

Well, one way to think about your question is to take $M = N = B$. (You can't get much flatter $B$-modules than this!)  Then you are asking that the natural map $B\otimes_A B \to B$ be an isomorphism, which is to say that the diagonal map
$$\mathrm{Spec} \, B \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Spec \, B}\otimes_{\mathrm{Spec} \, A} \mathrm{Spec} \, B$$
be an isomorphism.  This is asking that $A \to B$ be an epimorphism.

It is not so easy to find flat epimorphisms that are not localizations
(see the answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like), especially [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like/161#161)),
and so in practice I think that you should consider "$B$ is a localization of $A$" to be the most reasonable answer to the question of when this map is 
an isomorphism.