# Is the tensor product over $B$ of two flat $A$-modules flat over $A$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, flatness

Given a morphism of commutative rings $A\to B$ such that $B$ is a flat $A$-module and given $M$, $N$ two $B$-modules flat as $A$-modules, is the tensor product $M\otimes_B N$ flat over $A$??

The tensor product $M\otimes_A N$ is flat over $A$, the proof is not hard:

Given an exact sequence $0\to X\to Y\to Z\to 0$ of $A$-modules since $M$ is
a flat $A$-module the sequence $0\to X\otimes_A M\to Y\otimes_A M\to Z\otimes_A M\to 0$ is exact. Again $N$ is a flat $A$-module, and since the tensor commute we have the statement.

I've tried some similar arguments but without any success, and I can't find a counterexample.

There is a morphism $M\otimes_A N\to M\otimes_B N$ (it is shown in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55115/flat-algebras-and-tensor-product)), but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not in general, not even if $M$ and $N$ are, in fact $B$-algebras.  To see this, let $A = k[t]$ be the ring of polynomials in one indeterminate $t$ over a field $k$, and $B = k[x,y]$ be the ring of polynomials in two indeterminates $x,y$ over $k$ made into an $A$-algebra by mapping $t$ to $x+y$.  Let $M = B/(y)$ and $N = B/(x)$ be the quotient rings, emphatically not flat as $B$-modules but still flat as $A$-modules because in fact $M = k[x]$ with $t$ being mapped to $x$ and $N = k[y]$ with $t$ being mapped to $y$ are both even *isomorphic* to $A$.  Yet the tensor product $M \otimes_B N$ is $B / (x,y) = k$ which is not flat as an $A$-module.

This is probably easier to view geometrically: $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} M$ and $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} N$ are two lines in the plane $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} B$ whose intersection is a point: each line maps flatly, and even isomorphically, to the line $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} A$, but their intersection (which is their fiber product over the plane) does not map flatly.

Very nice question, though!

Answer (score 3):

*Assume that as $B$-modules, you have that $N= B\otimes_A N$*: note that this is generally false. There is an obvious map $B\otimes_A N\to N$ that sends $b\otimes n\to bn$. One might be tempted to use the functional inverse $n\to 1\otimes n$, but this is not necessarily $B$-linear, unless say $A\to B$ is onto. If it were true, then the argument goes through. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55115/flat-algebras-and-tensor-product?lq=1). As an example of how $B$ might definitely not be isomorphic to $B\otimes_A B$, take $B$ to be a $k$-algebra with $k$ a field, $k\to B$ the structure map, and say $B$ is finitely dimensional of dimension $>1$. Then $B\otimes_k B$ has dimension strictly greater than $B$.

Now take $C$ an exact sequence. Then $N\otimes_A C$ is exact, and since $B$ is flat, so is $B\otimes_A N\otimes_A C$. Now write $$M\otimes_B N =(M\otimes_A B)\otimes_B (B\otimes_A N)$$

Then $M\otimes_B N\otimes C$ is obtained from $B\otimes_A N\otimes_A C$ by tensoring first over $B$ with $B$, which preserves exactness, and then with $M$ over $A$, which also does.

Comment: I don't understand if you want to say that the answer to the question is positive, but in my opinion it's not. Moreover, for $M=N=B$ I think the equation $M\otimes_B N =(M\otimes_A B)\otimes_B (B\otimes_A N)$ is wrong.

Comment: Your answer is rather confusing: first you make a statement (italicized), then you say it's "generally false" (but not pointing out what assumption would make it true) and you give a counterexample *which has all the assumptions made in the original situation*, then you seem to use this statement, which you demonstrated to be false.  Did you perhaps mean "assume" instead of "note"?

Comment: @user26857 I corrected the incorrect claim, I'll try to rewrite if it is still unclear. The equation uses the initial assumption.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I made that statement, and upon realizing it was false, corrected the post.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I don't understand how the counterexample has "all the assumptions made in the original situation". If $B$ has dimension $>1$ then $k\to B$ is not surjective.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Please make me understand: this is a partial (positive) answer under the hypothesis $N=B\otimes_AN$?

Comment: @user26857 Yes. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe not, but honestly such a partial answer is very far from satisfying.

Comment: @user26857 Well, I agree.

Comment: I meant to say that your counterexample was a counterexample to your own statement with only the hypotheses in the original post — but as you fixed the first word "note" to "assume", I no longer have any objection.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, Thank you, but can you give some example where your extra hypotheses ($N\cong N\otimes_A B$) is satisfied?